# using azure data factory to unzip multiple files from http site

Tags: azure, zip, unzip, azure-data-factory

I have set up an "http file" data source in my ADF to connect to a specific URL (https://www.sos.wa.gov/_assets/corps/txtCorpsData.zip) which points to a ZIP file that contains 4 separate .txt files.

The service successfully connects and unzips the file but it's only reading the first file in the ZIP archive.  How do I make the source separate out into 4 different individual sources?  I'm guessing there's some parameter I need to use but not sure what that could be.

Here's a screenshot of the connection detail:
[connection detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAg72.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, kinda:
Using a "Copy Data" task that points to an "Http file" as the source.
     That "Http file" source then looks at the url from my question as a Linked Service, the source also deflates the ZIP.
Within the "Copy Data" task the sink is a blob connection.

When I run this task it deflates the ZIP file into a new folder underneath the path at the blob connection.  This presents a new issue that I'm working on now, which is that the new folder creation appears to be whatever the GUID is for the pipeline running, somehow I need to figure out a way to specify the folder name so it's consistent...I'll likely post another question asking that later.

Answer (score 0):

in the sink settings set the copy behavior to None, so that you can retain the file name
[image]